# Submitting a wordcount example to YARN (exception from SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:196)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:243)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:185)
at myHandler.handle(myHandler.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.NullPointerException): java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:196)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:243)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.submitApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:182)
... 9 more
```

Did I set invalid resources? I'm trying to make [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html) code alive.

I've found out that the `NullPointerException` got thrown from `ShedulerUtils.java @ line 196`, which is:

`if (resReq.getCapability().getMemory() < 0 ||
        resReq.getCapability().getMemory() > maximumResource.getMemory()) {
      throw new InvalidResourceRequestException("Invalid resource request"
          + ", requested memory < 0"
          + ", or requested memory > max configured"
          + ", requestedMemory=" + resReq.getCapability().getMemory()
          + ", maxMemory=" + maximumResource.getMemory());
    }`

So probably I did not set the capability (memory) for the container. How should I do it?

I've tried with:

`Resource capability = Records.newRecord(Resource.class);
    capability.setMemory(amMemory);
    amContainer.setResource(capability);`

But `ContainerLaunchContext amContainer` has no method `setResource`.

I'm running Hadoop 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give the `capability` to `ApplicationSubmissionContext`, not to `ContainerLaunchContext`, as the YARN example states.

Also, I've updated my Hadoop to 2.3.0.